# Add 2 Different Times and Return value in time(Formulae field) in HH:MM format

Tags: custom-field, timeout, time

[image: This is two custom fields of type text 1)Takeoff, 2)Duration,i validated the end client can only enter the time in HH:MM format, and then i want the result to be displayed in a formulae field called Landing by the adding the above two fields]
[image: This is Landing field formulae can someone help me out to write the formulae to find the result and display the result in text format]

I need results of two fields of type text in time format to be the same time format and then the result has to be time of HH:MM format aswell text in formulae field

Comment: In the above Question There are two custom fields of type "Text" which are 1)Takeoff(Text) and validation is (HH:MM) format 2)Duration (Text) and validation is (HH:MM) and then the above on adding should give the result in Landing Field in HH:MM format , Please help in formule

Comment: Are you looking for a formula field to find the difference between two time fields? which is in text?

Comment: @SamuelRobert formula but  not the difference i want takeoff+duration (HH:MM) format and then save the result in the Landing Text field where format should be same (HH:MM).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you intend to do when HH:MM goes beyond the 24 hour mark? Say your flight departs at 23:00 and takes 2 hours? Should it say 26:00? Or the more reasonable 01:00?

Comment: I would like the to display at what hour the flight has arrived on the summation of two fields in Landing field and the time standard should be 24hrs @kasper

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Formula fields are not the right tool for the job here. I'd highly suggest using Apex, and making your `Takeoff__c` and `Landing__c` fields `DateTime` instead of `Text`.

### Background

You're working with dates and times. **This is not something that formula fields can handle very well**. At the very least, formula fields can't handle it anywhere near as well as Apex can.

I know that the general Salesforce mantra is 'clicks before code', but if you try to do this with a formula field (if you'd even be able to stay under the character and compiled size limits) I have a feeling it would end up being a mess and a nightmare to maintain.

Salesforce doesn't have a field type strictly for holding time data (closest one is `DateTime`), so I'm guessing that your `Takeoff__c` and `Duration__c` fields are text fields. We can work with this, but I think it makes more sense for `Takeoff__c` and `Landing__c` fields to be of type `DateTime` instead. The reason using `DateTime` makes more sense here was mentioned in the comments on your question. What should happen if takeoff + duration puts your landing beyond 23:59? You could, of course, handle this situation manually, but `DateTime` does this for you, so why re-invent the wheel?

In my examples, I'll assume that you'll be changing those two fields from a text and formula field (respectively) to `DateTime` fields. I'll leave `Duration__c` as a text field in `HH:MM` format.

### Now we can start working

We want to calculate the `Landing__c` date/time by adding the duration to the `Takeoff__c` date/time. The [documentation on the `DateTime` class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) tells us that we have `addHours()` and `addMinutes()` methods, but those methods take `Integer` arguments. How do we turn your `Duration__c` text field into two integers?

The answer here has two parts. First, we use `String.split()` to break your duration field into two separate strings (`split()` actually returns a `List<String>`). Then, we need to take those strings, and convert them into integers using `Integer.valueOf()`.

The code snippet for that would look like this

```
// In this case, the delimiter that separates hours from minutes is ':'
// It would be wise to include some null checks in your actual code.
List<String> durations = myRec.Duration__c.split(':');
// Assuming that Duration__c is formatted like 1:35, durations will contain ['1', '35']
//   at this point in the code

// Lists are zero-indexed (i.e. the first element is index 0)
// Given the format above, hours will always be index 0, and minutes always index 1
Integer durationHours = Integer.valueOf(durations[0]);
Integer durationMinutes = Integer.valueOf(durations[1]);
```

From there, calculating `Landing__c` is trivial

```
// addHours() and addMinutes() both return a DateTime, so method chaining like this 
//   should be possible
myRec.Landing__c = myRec.Takeoff__c.addHours(durationHours).addMinutes(durationMinutes);

// If the above gives you an error, then you'll need to use the following instead.
// Note that the second operation is applied to Landing__c instead of Takeoff__c.
// This is because DateTime operations don't alter the DateTime that we call the method on.
// If you were to use Takeoff__c for the second operation, it would overwrite
//   Landing__c, and you'd end up with a value of Landing__c that is only minutes
//   after Takeoff__c.
// myRec.Landing__c = myRec.Takeoff__c.addHours(durationHours);
// myRec.Landing__c = myRec.Landing__c.addMinutes(durationMinutes);
```

4 lines of code, after all is said and done. Not too shabby (and a whole lot shorter than a formula field's formula would be). It could even be taken down to a single line of code if you wanted (though I'd personally stop after taking it down to two lines of code).

### If you're really insistent on keeping everything as text fields

It's still possible (easy, even) to do this with Apex. You'd just call `String.split()` on `Takeoff__c` as well. You would need to add additional logic to prevent getting nonsensical hour/minute values for `Landing__c` (which, while easy enough, is why I suggest using `DateTime` fields where possible. DateTime takes care of that for you).

```
List<String> durations = myRec.Duration__c.split(':');
List<String> takeoffs  = myRec.Takeoff__c.split(':');

Integer landingHour = Integer.valueOf(durations[0]) + Integer.valueOf(takeoffs[0]);
Integer landingMinute = Integer.valueOf(durations[1]) + Integer.valueOf(takeoffs[1]);

// If our minutes is > 59, we need to add at least 1 to the landingHour.
// Plain, old Integer division should do the trick.
// 75/60 = 1, 125/60 = 2.
// landingMinute % 60 ensures that our minute value is between 0 and 59 (inclusive)
if(landingMinute > 59){
    landingHour += landingMinute / 60;
    landingMinute = landingMinute % 60;
}

// Also need to do a check for landingHour
if(landingHour > 23){
    landingHour = landingHour % 24;
}

myRec.Landing__c = String.valueOf(landingHour) + ':' + String.valueOf(landingMinute);
```

10 lines of code is still not bad, but not nearly as good as if `Takeoff__c` and `Landing__c` were `DateTime` fields.